# iframe overflow doesn't work normally in IE

Tags: html, css

how to create an overflow div in IE?
its seems that my method can work normally using other browser (chrome, firefox), but not in IE.
Here is my code:

```
<div style="height:400px;overflow:auto">
<div class="fb-comments fb_iframe_widget" style="overflow:hidden;position:relative" data-href="#" data-width="470" data-num-posts="10" fb-xfbml-state="rendered">
<span style="height: 905px; width: 470px;position:relative;">
<iframe id="f225f010c" name="fe2e48c68" scrolling="yes" style="position:relative;border: none; overflow: hidden; height: 905px; width: 470px;" class="fb_ltr" src="#"></iframe>
</span>
</div>
</div>
```

I've try so many methods, but none of them were work.
Any suggestion?
Thank you very much

Comment: which version of IE? Have you declared your DOCTYPE?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a MIN-HEIGHT and not a HEIGHT. Then use that in conjunction with OVERFLOW:AUTO.

Comment: I've tried to set it as min-height instead of height, but it still doesn't work. In IE it still shows all of the content and which can't be scrolled. However it works perfectly in chrome.

Comment: I'll repeat my question then. Which version of IE?

Comment: IE 8. Actually it works normally if I didn't declare any DOCTYPE, but if I declared the DOCTYPE, it became can't work.